# How To Make Chrome Use A VPN When Visiting A Specific Website

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

Is there any way to make Google Chrome use a VPN when visiting a specific website? Like the VPN will activate while I am on that site but when I leave it deactivates.

Comment: You could automate something to setup a proxy I suppose as one idea and once the proxy is setup then go to the site via command line passing the URL to the browser EXE... There's you a starting point so get to work and let us know what you come up with that shows what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this extension that bypass and change your ip 
remember to connect when you want to visit those websites

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjn49--yufUAhWOKFAKHU34BYIQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fultrasurf-security-privac%2Fmjnbclmflcpookeapghfhapeffmpodij%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGhclQSbAxr5YjodI1WEgfjMXOSZg

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: this extension should do the job but you have to configure it

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm?hl=en